# Move/Resize Partition

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, linux-mint

I had dual boot on my computer run W10 and Linux Mint, so after test Linux to programming, I decided to remove the partition where contains w10. So far so good.

Now the partition stays on left, and I can resize/move to join another partition.. (img)

[image]

I wish to join 31gb partition to 87 GB or 131 GB doesn't matter.

How I can do this without formatting my PC, It's possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reboot of a live distro (not sure if mint allows you use w/o install) and use gparted. Delete the current NTFS partition, extend Partition 6 if you want to. If you want 5 to be bigger, move 6 to the left and then add the free space to 5.

Comment: Yes, Linux Mint can be as well

Answer (score 1):

Moving partition 6 to the left would be required first, reading then writing every sector, before you can add the free space (old partition 4) to partition 6's right. That's pretty slow, and a power failure could be catastrophic so a backup would be prudent.

If the free space were on the right, you could simply & quickly extend the partition (ext extends wonderfully).

Another option is to just reformat partition 4 to ext, then use it as more storage, perhaps as a link in your home.